# Ошибка при отправке Post запроса с Pythonanywhere. Что делать?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, post, вконтакте, multipart

Всем  привет , возникла проблема при формировании post запроса с хоста Pythonanywhere. Сам в запросах не новичок, однако разобраться с этим не смог. Мне нужно с помощью vk бота отправлять документы формата .docx в личные сообщения к собеседнику. На компьютере код выполняется на ура, а на Pythonanywhere - не может найти файл. Вот мой код:

```
import requests
l = vk_session.method("docs.getMessagesUploadServer",{"peer_id": id, "type": "doc", "v": "5.73"})
req = requests.post(url=l['upload_url'],files={"file": open("file.docx","rb")},headers={"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"})
r = vk_session.method("docs.save", {"file": jreq["file"], "title": baza[num]["old"][2], "tags":"документ","return_tags": 0})
```

В l я присваиваю специальный url, который я получаю с серверов vk(в доках так). Затем формирую post запрос формата multipart/form-data. Третьей строчкой происходит сохранение документа на серверах vk. Теперь об ошибке. На Pythonanywhere при выводе контента req.content(), пишет следующее:

```
{'error': 'no_file', 'error_descr': 'no_file'}
```

С ошибкой:
`<class 'KeyError'>, KeyError('file'), <traceback object at 0x7f9562a21140>`
Помогите пожалуйста, уже 2 дня решить проблему не могу.

Comment: *>запрос формата multipart/form-data*, >`headers={"Content-Type":"application/json` - ????

Answer (score 0):

На Pythonanywhere вы можете настроить папки во вкладке `Web > Code`.

Советую запускать в консоли команды `os.getcwd()` и `os.listdir()`, чтобы определить в каком окружении вы находитесь.